# How do I fix Google Chrome's large icon in its Windows 10 Start Menu tile?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, start-menu, tiles

When I pin Google Chrome to the Start Menu, the browser's icon is unusually large. This is the first time I pinned Chrome to the Start Menu after a few months and it wasn't like this before. It used to be like the other apps pinned in the menu.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

The Google Chrome tile (second column of tiles, third row) seems to be occupying the whole tile space. It's also the same with resizing the tile from medium to small.

How do I fix this? Thank you.

**Update:** I tried doing [Krusted.com's method](http://krusted.com/guides/large-google-chrome-icon-fix/) which was given to me below but the tile went blank. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Source: [Large Google Chrome Icon Fix - Krusted](http://krusted.com/guides/large-google-chrome-icon-fix/)

Rename the Visualelementsmanifest.xml in Google Chrome's program directory.
Then move the Google Chrome shortcut from:

`%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
to
your Desktop or somewhere else.

Again move the shortcut back to the original location where it was.

This works 100%.

The following page has a Vbscript to automate the task.

[Google Chrome Start Screen Tile Icon Fix (Script) for Windows 10](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/google-chrome-start-tile-icon-fix-script/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer w32sh, but it didn't work out as planned. The tile is now blank. Maybe there's another solution for this? I updated the post with a screenshot after doing the method. Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind I found a solution in the comments of the post in Krusted. 
Comment of Christian Ullrich • 4 days ago
- "Thanks for the tip. It did not work as intended for me; the icon was blank afterwards, so I removed the Square150x150Logo attribute from the manifest file instead. That fixed it. Now if only the next Chrome update does not revert that ..."

Comment: Thanks for the update. If the xml doesn't exist it seems to take the shortcut icon if customized. If not, it users the Chrome icon from executable.